# Angular-cli How are the type files loaded?

Tags: jquery, webpack, angular-cli

Okay I am having the strangest day. I am using jQuery and Bootstrap in an angular-cli project and I just can't understand how it is able to locate the type files for typescript without me even specifying where they are.

Example-:

I have loaded the jquery and bootstrap files via the angular-cli globally. I don't even have to declare the jquery variable like the following-:

```
declare var $ : JQueryStatic;
```

VS Code gets intellisense automatically and the compilation works fine.

Now here is the really weird part-:

When I am using jQuery plugins like typeahead.js I somehow have to import the jquery module like the following-:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

---

```
$("#state_input").typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        }, {
                name: 'states',
                source: this.sourceFactory(this.states)
            });
```

If I don't do that then the above code fails. It fails with the message `typeahead is not a function` AT RUN TIME.

It compiles fine.

**What does importing the jquery module separately here change, when I didn't need to import it before and it is globally loaded ?**

I am really losing my mind because of the lack of consistency.

Comment: Have you added the scripts in the angular-cli.json file.

Comment: @Jai I have added jQuery and bootstrap.min.js in my angular.cli.json but I have not added typeahead.js anywhere in my angular-cli.json file

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three different possibilities:

A) Check if you have `typeahead` defined in `src/typings.d.ts`, e.g.:

```
interface JQuery {
    typeahead(options?:any):JQuery;
}
```

B) Check your `node_modules/@types` folder to see if there's any `typeahead` typing installed.

C) Check if `node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts` is not standard jQuery, but a twitter/bootstrap/typeahead custom version that includes typings for typeahead (do ctrl+f (or command+f if using a mac) and search for typeahead in that file). In this case, the folder might not even be called `jquery`, so take a look in any other suspicious folders.

VS Code is getting its autocomplete suggestions from one of these places. Having the typings installed helps the IDE autocomplete but it doesn't necessarily mean that you have the packages installed, that's why it fails in the browser.

Edit:

D) A fourth possibility could be that the typing is defined elsewhere. Search for *.d.ts files in your project folder to see if anything comes up somewhere in non-standard places.

Comment: I get the fact VSCode maybe getting types from the locations you mentioned above, but how the heck is the typescript compiler getting them ?

Comment: Whatever file you include in your `angular-cli.json` is ignored by VS Code, VS Code gets its intellisense feature from type files as explained in my answer. Later, when compiling (actually it is called transcompiling), all the js files are also "ignored" by the compiler as they are already in Javascript. All your TypeScript code gets transcompiled to Javascript. The js files specified in `angular-cli.json` get bundled into your application (and minified) and made available to the rest of the app. Does this help you understand better what you asked for? If it does, I'll update the answer.

Comment: No that was not what I meant. Correct me if I am wrong my doesn't the typescript transpiler need the `d.ts` file for transpiling ? So when when it transpiles to JS where does it get it from ? I can understand the IDE maybe smart when to find it but where does the `tsc` compiler get it from ?

Comment: Yes. Basically, declaration files tell the compiler "this symbol exists, it is ok to use it" or "I don't know that symbol, throw an error here". These come from `.d.ts` files, not `.js`. `js` files might not even be actually included and the compiler wont fail cos it assumes they WILL be there bundled later, but of course you'll get runtime errors if they are not actually there in the end. Head over here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Architectural-Overview#overview-of-the-compilation-process to get a deeper picture on how the compiler works.

Comment: Just tell me something, the checking that is done by VSCode/IDE when I am typing out my code is different than that of `tsc` compiler when angular-cli builds my app right ? I guess I am confusing these things.

Comment: No, it's the same, both do it with `.d.ts` files. Try removing something from a `.d.ts` file that you are currently using and you'll see VS Code will underline your code in that part immediately. As I tried to explain before, the `.d.ts` files describe what's in the `js` files. The `js` files should be included in `angular-cli.json` to be later bundled with the app when compiled, but none the IDE or the compiler rely on these files when checking the code. The `.d.ts` files are what "describe" the files (tell what's in them).